# Jquery css : what's the difference between these two types of hover text

Tags: jquery, html, css

total jquery newb here and I'm wondering what the difference in therse two types of text that appear when you hover over something  and if someone can explain what both of them are, thank a lot.

First hover text :
 when you hover over the up-vote or down-vote here on stackoverflow you will see two different messages that appear in a yellow box.

Second hover text:

https://twitter.com/#!/BRAINFEEDER

when you hover over a recommended person's image or hover over the small circles to the right of the 'Follow' button, a black box appears with a small triangle and describes what you are hovering.

Really appreciate any information thanks again

Comment: It is called a **tooltip**. The first one is generated by default browser's tooltip mechanism, the second one is a result of JavaScript script and CSS styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stackoverflow when you hover over the voted arrow  is called a `tooltip` which  is generated by default browser's for this we use `title`
write this:

```
<a title="This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)">up vote</a>
```

On the other like in twitter is a `custom tooltip` which your created with `css` & if you want some animation you can use `javascript` also.

Write like this:

**html:**

```
<a class="parent">
 <span class="tooltip">hello</span>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
.tooltip{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
  left:-10x;
}
.parent:hover .tooltip{
 display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the hover effects you see on the stackoverflow vote up or down are tooltips; user agents style them and you can't alter them. they apply by default if you use a title attribute on an html element; when you hover over the element, the tool tip shows.

the hover effects you see on twitter when you look @ a user's icon, displaying their name, are styled with css and (i'm assuming) applied via JavaScript; there's not much to look at in the source, and inspect element doesn't show a title attribute on the a element or the img element.